# Safely call methods

Tags: ruby

Is there a nice way how to write:

```
a = one.two.three.four
```

where "one" - assigned, "two" - nil. This statement makes an exception.

I want to have "a" nil if any of "two", "three", "four" are nil, otherwise to have result of "four" in "a".

Is it possible to do this without writing condition statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = one.try(:two).try(:three).try(:four)
```

Comment: How to write this:
a = one.two.three(param)[:c]

Comment: -1. I'd argue that `try`, when used in a method chain like this, is a code smell. Although it *is* a solution to '*safely call methods*', the idea of safely calling methods chained together like OP has posted is not right, IMO.

Comment: @Andrew: It is, but that doesn't mean it isn't a code smell. There has been a lot of discussion over `try`. And the intended use is definitely not in chaining.

Comment: @Swanand: Actually, I was meaning to gently hint that the OP hadn't mentioned that they were using Rails.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to find out if this code violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). If that is the case, then the correct solution to this problem is to **not write** code this way.

How would you find out if its breaking it? [Here](http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/) is one article that tries to explain how that applies to Ruby language.

In your case, you would break it down into multiple calls, with guard clauses around it. In the call `one.two.three.four`, we can assume that `four` is a property of `three` (rather, the object returned by `three`). And `three` would be a property of `two`. So you would add a method in `two`:

```
# Note: This is an over-simplified example
def three_four
  return unless three
  three.four
end
```

And in `one` you would have:

```
def two_three_four
  return unless two
  two.three_four
end
```

A more relevant example:

```
invoice.customer.primary_address.zipcode
```

So you would have `Customer#primary_address_zipcode` and `Invoice#customer_primary_address_zip_code` (Or a better abbreviated name, that would make more sense)